# Installing RStudio using Anaconda Navigator in Windows 10

Tags: r, anaconda, rstudio

I tried to install RStudio from Anaconda Navigator GUI. I ran the Anaconda Navigator with administrator privileges. Once the installation is started, a pop-up appears to create 'rstudio' environment in `C:\Users\bipin\Anaconda3\envs\rstudio`. The installation went on for sometime. So when the installation was over, the button beneath RStudio icon shows 'Install'(instead of 'Launch'). Hence I went to the very folder(`C:\Users\bipin\Anaconda3\envs\rstudio`) to check for the installed files. I was startled to discover that the 'rstudio' folder was missing in the 'envs' folder.

I repeated the process several times, however the result was same.

Should I install R from 'https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/'?

I would appreciate feedback to rectify this issue.

Comment: Are you looking to use RStudio as a text editor for python? What is your end goal?

Comment: I want to use RStudio for R. I am a beginner in R.

Comment: Then you first need to download R, then RStudio. The latter is basically a fancy text editor for R.

Comment: It worked finally...